# How to make function ondelete cascade in Laravel delete function

Tags: mysql, laravel, cascade

I want to delete this meeting room which the table reference to other table by foreign key. But when I deleted it shows an error :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`siiteung_prod`.`booking_ruang`, CONSTRAINT `fk_id_ruang` FOREIGN KEY (`id_ruang`) REFERENCES `ruang_rapat` (`id_ruang`)) (SQL: delete `ruang_rapat` from `ruang_rapat` inner join `booking_ruang` on `booking_ruang`.`id_ruang` = `ruang_rapat`.`id_ruang` where `ruang_rapat`.`id_ruang` = 109 and `booking_ruang`.`id_ruang` = 109)

And this is my current code that I want to add ondelete cascade, is it possible?

```
DB::table('ruang_rapat')
        ->where('id_ruang', $id)
        ->delete();
```

Otherwise, I can change ondelete & onupdate to cascade in navicat but it's not allowed by my boss. Thanks, hope u're helping me because I really stressed out.

Comment: on delete/update cascade can only be defined on the table itself and not while running a query and in you case your project requirements forbid doing this. You'd have to cascade the delete manually e.g. `DB::table('booking_ruang')->where('id_ruang', $id)->delete();` before you run the delete on `ruang_rapat`.

Comment: Ah, why it didn't occur to me. Thanks it works man!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define, the foreign key relation with cascade in MySQL to perform the delete.

or if you creating the table with migration then you need to define the relation in migration
something like below:

```
Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    `enter code here`
    $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: yes i can change to cascade but it's not allowed. My current table is not migration too so I can't define relation in migration

Comment: yes because you need to truncate your parent table. because you can define relation only on empty table, while create a table.
so truncate both table and then create proper relation between them.